# OS X Lion: What is uninstalld?

Tags: process, cpu-usage, osx-lion

Every now and then, since I installed Lion on my Mac, I have noticed that a process called `uninstalld` has been running and using a *lot* of CPU time.

Does anyone know what it does? I haven't tried to uninstall anything.

Answer (score 1):

`uninstalld` appears to belong to a new "Uninstall" framework that comes with OS X Lion.

It sits in: `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Uninstall.framework/Resources/uninstalld`

What does it do? I don't know specifically, but here's [what AppleInsider says](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/11/02/28/inside_mac_os_x_10_7_lion_server_remote_lock_disk_wipe_and_administration.html) (based on [a blog entry](http://imarck90.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/mac-os-x-lion-my-review-and-news/) here):

> Additionally, the discovery of a new Uninstall.framework indicates
>   that new Profile Server remote management tools (a feature of Lion
>   Server for both Mac and iOS clients) will enable network
>   administrators to **remotely manage the software installed and removed
>   on an organizations' machines**, in addition to managing profiles
>   (configuration files that are currently used to set up new iOS
>   devices, and will in the future be used to set up Lion Macs).

Comment: In addition: Do you have OS X Lion Server installed? And does it hurt your performance?

Comment: It is worth clarifying that, in most cases, so long as applications aren't competing for CPU time, it doesn't matter if one background process is using a lot. It's quite possible that it's running as a low priority process, in which case if you are running other things it should get out of your way, and not hurt perf at all.

With all that said, I do have to note that my install of OS X Lion (not the Server version) is not running uninstalld. I'm not quite sure why that is, but it's a bit weird.

Comment: @slhck I don't have OS X Lion Server installed.

Comment: @Lukasa I suspect it's low priority. It also seems to come and go. It's not running at the moment, but I saw it again a couple of days ago.

Comment: @Stephen I think you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I apologise for the delay in my replies to these answers: the notification landed in my spam trap...

Comment: @slhck I'm not so much worried about it: I just like to know what my computer is up to :-)

Comment: Once it starts, it tends to run at 100% CPU usage until I kill it. I don't notice any adverse effects from killing it. Using a whole core nonstop tends to eat my battery.